# Fluid Organisms Using Long Chain Perfluorinated Ethers

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design

I recently heard about "self-siphoning fluids" like polypropylene glycol and was reminded of Venom. My thought process is that the cell could have polymer chains extending from its cell membrane that interlock with those of neighbouring cells which is what holds the organism together. It would have to be a perfluorinated ether to keep it from absorbing or being dissolved in whatever it crawls/flows over.

My question isn't if this could evolve but if it could work.

Answer (score 4):

Not really, but it could be close.

Essentially, a few things would be required. The first is  the chain itself, which at a guess is best done by using the already existing flagella structure found on bacteria. Flagella aren't used for this purpose, so we're going to replace it with essentially a cat o' nine tails of long polymers (very, very long polymers). Hopefully, that should give us enough interaction and distribute the weight. As long as we're doing this, we're also shrinking the bacteria to as small as possible, which is more or less a given considering bacteria, but as small as possible. Also, we're putting our long polymer tails at both ends, but just ends. We don't want a sea urchins, because I'm afraid that may cause too much interaction.

Now, living matter usually isn't a liquid, or forms together as liquid. The reasons for this vary, naturally, but cells like to surround themselves with a stable barrier, and thus the whole 'living matter as a solid' thing. Fortunately, our infeasible amount of ether polymer chains may give us a bit of leeway in that regard, and allow it to form a slime state.

The problem is that here is where I have to stop. This structure will work for a self-pouring living goop, but each cell needs to be self-sufficient and thus structure and communication between cells is all but impossible. It also would be subject exclusively to external forces for movement. Not to mention the intake of resources would be a nightmare as well.